# unknown existence of bijection

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, proof-explanation, cardinals

[Here](https://math.uchicago.edu/~mem/mm-quantifiers-final.pdf) on the page 4
in the proof of fact 2.6(a)
,
I do not follow why there is a bijection $$g:\lambda\to\cal P_{\aleph_0}(p)$$
so that we can fix it.
We only require $$|A|\leq\lambda,$$ so $\cal P_{\aleph_0}(p)$ may not be large enough ensuring that we can choose $g$ **injective**. Perhaps there is some item on that page 4, so that this bijection fixing can be done (i.e. that a bijection $g$ exists)?

Comment: Could you provide more context? What is $\lambda$? What is $p$? What is $\mathcal{P}_{\aleph_0}(p)$?

Comment: @Taroccoesbrocco Juts click on that link from the first word of my original question. Everything is defined in the fact 2.6 (otherwise I would define it myself if that were scattered on multiple places in the paper).

Comment: @Taroccoesbrocco $\lambda$ is an infinite cardinal, $p$ is a type over $A$ and $\cal P_{\aleph_0}(p)$ are finite subsets of the type $p$.